# react-native undefined is not an object (evaluating RCCManager.setRootController)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to make a simple react-native app with redux and redux-saga tie-ins. Unfortunately, when I try to run the app (whether using `react-native run-ios` or running through Xcode, I get the following error:

[image: error message: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCCManager.setRootController')]

Strangely enough, when I ported things like the Counter example for redux-saga to react-native or other examples I don't have this issue. I'm wondering if someone could help point to where things could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out I just needed to link some more libraries together.

Reinstalling these components helped:

`npm install --save react-native`
and
`npm install --save react-native-controllers`

followed by `rnpm link` fixed the issue

Comment: The above did't helped me!! . what else could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution based on my own failure: 
Through rechecking [iOS installation doc](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-ios), I found out some tricky differences in the #4 requirement:
[image] It clearly says **project row** instead of **target row**. This time I selected  **'project'** row and add do what the #4 instruction told to do. Then it solved the problem. Hopefully my solution will be found helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and it was because somehow the setup I made for the Xcode project were lost, so following the [instructions](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-ios) I made them again and the problem was solved.